# how do I handle this gcc/os error in python?

Tags: python, gcc, try-except

I've been trying to handle errors using Python try except

```
try:
     command_result = os.popen("gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c11 " + prog_path + " -lm")
except:
     print("failed to compile your code")
     exit()
```

but when I intentionally give it the wrong prog_path it gives me the following error:

`gcc: error: [prog_path]: No such file or directory`

i.e. it doesn't execute code under except

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception raised because it is not python raising the error.
You are executing some command and getting the execution result, in this case an error message.

For this particular case, I would use `os.path.exists()` instead of a try/except block.

```
import os

path = '/usr/local/bin/'
if os.path.exists(path):
    print('doing stuff...')
else:
    print(f"can't find {path}")
```